# Return to switch case from a function

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm new to c# and I'm currently doing an assignment where I have to create a menu with a `switch` case where the user types either A, B, C or D and each one either goes to a Fahrenheit to Celsius converter, a change from coins, a number pattern or to exit the menu respectively. I just finished coding the Fahrenheit converter (hopefully correctly) but I need to go back to the switch case.

Currently my code:

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
namespace cSharp_Assignment
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Console.WriteLine("Type A to go to Fahrenheit Converter");
            Console.WriteLine("Type B to go to Coin Change");
            Console.WriteLine("Type C to go to Number Pattern");
            string menuChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            switch (menuChoice)
            {
                case "A":
                    fahrenheitConverter();
                    break;
                case "B":

                    break;
                case "C":

                    break;
                case "D":
                    break;
            }
        }
        public static void fahrenheitConverter()
        {
            int Fahrenheit = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Insert a temperature in Fahrenheit");
            Console.ReadLine();
            int Celcius = ((Fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9));
            Console.WriteLine("Celcius is: " + Celcius);                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to go back to"? The method will already return there... and after that, your program will finish. If you mean you want to offer the menu again, you probably want a loop...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is currently not very clear. After the `fahrenheitConverter()` method has finished, the execution will automatically return to where `fahrenheitConverter()` was called.

Comment: this typically just means putting a `while` loop (often `while(true)`) around the code you want to keep repeating... so : at a minimum, around the `ReadLine()` and the `switch` - it is up to you whether to show the instructions each time...

Comment: You mean that your menu should appear again enabling the user to run again?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, to clarify I wanted it to return to the menu (switch case) so you could choose another one of the options. Using a loop was all I needed to fix it as it would completely exit and I wouldn't be able to see if my converter actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

add a while statement with the exit condition you want, "X" in your case

```
    while (menuChoice != "X")
    {
        switch (menuChoice)
        {
            case "A":
                fahrenheitConverter();
                break;
            case "B":

                break;
            case "C":

                break;
            case "D":
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Type A to go to Fahrenheit Converter");
        Console.WriteLine("Type B to go to Coin Change");
        Console.WriteLine("Type C to go to Number Pattern");
        Console.WriteLine("Type X to exit");
        menuChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    }
```

Your main should look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type A to go to Fahrenheit Converter");
    Console.WriteLine("Type B to go to Coin Change");
    Console.WriteLine("Type C to go to Number Pattern");
    Console.WriteLine("Type X to exit");
    string menuChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

    while (menuChoice != "X")
    {
        switch (menuChoice)
        {
            case "A":
                fahrenheitConverter();
                break;
            case "B":

                break;
            case "C":

                break;
            case "D":
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Type A to go to Fahrenheit Converter");
        Console.WriteLine("Type B to go to Coin Change");
        Console.WriteLine("Type C to go to Number Pattern");
        Console.WriteLine("Type X to exit");
        menuChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at including some sort of loop with an exit condition...

I'm not going to give you c# code, as this looks like an assignment, but here's the pseudo...

```
while (UpperCase(menuChoice)!="EXIT")
{

            Console.WriteLine("Type A to go to Fahrenheit Converter");
            Console.WriteLine("Type B to go to Coin Change");
            Console.WriteLine("Type C to go to Number Pattern");
            string menuChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            switch (menuChoice)
            {
                case "A":
                    fahrenheitConverter();
                    break;
                case "B":

                    break;
                case "C":

                    break;
                case "D":
                    break;
            }

}
```

Comment: There's no need for the `UpperCase` in the while loop, since menuChoice is `ToUpper` anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. All you have to do is to *add one loop* more, e.g.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  // Keep on working (execute switch case) ...
  for (bool keepOnWorking = true; keepOnWorking;) {
    Console.WriteLine("Type A to go to Fahrenheit Converter");
    Console.WriteLine("Type B to go to Coin Change");
    Console.WriteLine("Type C to go to Number Pattern");
    Console.WriteLine("Type X to exit");

    // Trim: let us be nice (what if user put/paste "A " or " B"?)
    string menuChoice = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpper();

    switch (menuChoice) {
      case "A":
        fahrenheitConverter();
        break;
      case "B":
        break;
      case "C":
        break;
      case "D":
        break;
      case "X":
        // ... until user press "X". Stop working 
        keepOnWorking = false; 
        break; 
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the main method again. It is easy. And it should work. But not recommended.
Hope this helps. Regards..!

```
  using System;    
  using System.Collections.Generic;    
  using System.Linq;    
  using System.Text;    
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace cSharp_Assignment
  {    
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        Console.WriteLine("Type A to go to Fahrenheit Converter");
        Console.WriteLine("Type B to go to Coin Change");
        Console.WriteLine("Type C to go to Number Pattern");
        string menuChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

        switch (menuChoice)
        {
            case "A":
                fahrenheitConverter();
                break;
            case "B":

                break;
            case "C":

                break;
            case "D":
                break;
        }
    }
    public static void fahrenheitConverter()
    {
        int Fahrenheit = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Insert a temperature in Fahrenheit");
        Console.ReadLine();
        int Celcius = ((Fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9));
        Console.WriteLine("Celcius is: " + Celcius); 

        Main(null); // Just call the main method here. This should work. But not recomended   
    }
}
```

}